# Better Way to Deal with Data from Database and Lists

Tags: database, list, performance, search, software-quality

1. I have `TextField` and `onChange` function it filters `ListView`, so is it better get whole item from table and save them in list then when change text filter that list or open stream get data from table every single change in search `TextField`?
2. I have lists in my app with elements, is it preferable when I go to another page or when I don't use the items, clear them every time or it is ok, it doesn't affect the app?

Comment: Which GUI library are you using?

Comment: I mean in general what is the best way

Comment: Looks at the design patterns for "Push vs Pull models for UI"